# How to use `tbl` command for more than 72 lines?

Tags: troff, tbl

I used `tbl` command to format the data in a tabular format and it worked fine for a file which contain 71 lines and when I added another line in the file it break with below error -

`error: page 2: table will not fit on one page; use .TS H/.TH with a supporting macro package`

then I looked at the man page and found the same info. and tried all possible combination of use `.TS` and `.TE` in input file. Please share your solution if you have came across this kind of problem.

snapshot of command that I am using - 
`cat file.txt
.TS
tab(:)
ce|ce|ce|ce|ce|ce
row1-col1:col2:col3:col4:col5:col6
row2-cola:colb:colc:cold:cole:colf
.......
.......
row72-cola:colb:colc:cold:cole:colf
.TE`

Passing this file to `tbl` command like below -

`tbl file.txt|groff -T ascii`

Is there a way to use `.TS`, `.TH` and '.TE` to process more than 71 lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to print the output in tabular format using `tbl` for multi page -

`.TS H
tab(:)
ce|ce|ce|ce|ce|ce
.TH
row1-col1:col2:col3:col4:col5:col6
row2-cola:colb:colc:cold:cole:colf
.......
.......
row72-cola:colb:colc:cold:cole:colf
.TE`

And need to use this file like below -

`tbl file.txt|groff -ms -T ascii`